# Could somebody explain the color format, 0xARGB?

Tags: java, colors

I was reading an article, where the color format, 0xARGB, was used. I tried googling around, but couldn't find anything.

The article used the color, 0xcc008500, in his project, and it showed as dark green.

I would like an explanation on why this format is used like this, and if there is anywhere or any method I can use to find, for example how to write the color "white", using this format.

I do understand that the last 6 characters show the HEX-value, if that is to any help. Thanks!

btw, I know that there is a similar question on here, but I don't think our questions are the same.

Thanks.

Comment: All 8 digits are in hex. It's a four-byte value. The A is for "Alpha", and indicates the transparancy. ARGB is really a different ordering for [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space).

Comment: And the format is commonly known as `ARGB`, not `0xARGB`.

Comment: Yeah I thought so as well. Is there a way I can PM you? Maybe on Twitter if you have that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A represents alpha channel and it defines transparency of image.
[Useful info](https://coderwall.com/p/dedqca/argb-colors-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Well it the whole value is just an hexadecimal value.

In fact your color is made of 4 channels : the alpha layer (giving the transparency) and then the red, green and blue channels. Each channel is represented by a byte (2 hex characters). See ARGB section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)